# JavaScript: сравнение по типу переменной

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить переменную по её типу? Например, если это число делать одно, а если строка, то другое, если объект, то третье?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте операторы [**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) и [**instanceof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) (об их различиях [написано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6625960/5308802)):

```
var data;
data = ...;

if (typeof data === 'string') {
    // строка
}

if (typeof data === 'number') {
    // число
}

if (data instanceof Array) {
    // массив
}

if (data instanceof Object) {
    // объект / словарь
}
```

Comment: С массивом не так просто. Нужно использовать `Array.isArray`.

Comment: @Other, в большинстве случаев `instanceof` вполне справится же?

Comment: Есть нюанс с null.

Comment: В большинстве случаев вообще можно забить на [нюансы](http://web.mit.edu/jwalden/www/isArray.html). Но стоит ли?